# forward tcp requests through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have 3 devices:

1. A server, connected to Network1
2. A laptop, connected to Network2
3. A Raspberry Pi, also connected to Network2

There is also a openVPN server on Network1, plus port forwarding for accessing VPN.

I need the Raspi to recieve TCP requests(meant for the server) from the laptop and send them through the VPN to the server, then send the response from the server back to the laptop. Only one port will be used, but it would also be fine if all ports got forwarded. no software can be installed on the laptop. Also preferably no commands or such on the laptop.

I need some sort of "port forwarding" but into a vpn

Comment: You can add a route on the laptop via the pi. In Windows for example, it would look like `route /p add [Network1] mask [mask] [Pi IP]`. On the Pi, enable traffic forwarding in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, by setting `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`. You may also need to configure NAT on the pi or add a matching route on the server, depending on your vpn configuration. Google "raspberry pi as a router" for more details

Comment: Sorry, I meant without any handelings on the laptop. The laptop isn't mine, and I would like someone else to connect to my server, with only the pi on there network and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use literally the same "port forwarding", i.e. DNAT rules in the router's (RasPi's) firewall; it functions the same way regardless of network type.

That is, add `DNAT` iptables or nftables rules to the RasPi firewall for each "port-forward" that you need. (Don't forget to also add 'allow forward' rules – these are automatic in most routers, but not automatic in plain iptables or nftables.)

Your server must have a route back to Network2 through its VPN connection (in OpenVPN that likely means an `iroute` configuration). If that's difficult to set up, the alternative is to have the RasPi also do `SNAT` or `MASQUERADE` in addition to DNAT-ing. (The SNAT/MASQ option would be exactly the same kind of config as for "NAT hairpinning" in LANs.)

- Example for nftables:

  ```
  table inet filter {
      chain forward {
          type filter hook forward priority filter;

          ip daddr <ServerIP> accept
      }
  }

  table ip nat {
      chain prerouting {
          type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat;

          iifname "eth0" ip daddr <RasPiIP> tcp dport 80 \
            dnat to <ServerIP>:80
      }

      chain postrouting {
          type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat;

          oifname "tun0" masquerade
      }
  }
  ```
- Example for iptables:

  ```
  -t filter -I FORWARD -d <ServerIP> -j ACCEPT

  -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -d <RasPiIP> -p tcp --dport 80 \
      -j DNAT --to-destination <ServerIP>:80

  -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
  ```

Alternative: Use a "reverse proxy" on the RasPi. Most reverse proxies are for HTTP/HTTPS, but any TCP or TLS protocol can be proxied. This won't work with UDP (not easily, at least) and needs additional software but has fewer routing requirements.

For HTTP/HTTPS services, Nginx or Apache httpd would be common choices; widely documented elsewhere. (In both, the option is called "proxy_pass" or "ProxyPass".)

Comment: and... how do i do that?

Comment: That depends on which firewall you're currently using on the Pi?

Comment: i installed raspberry pi os lite(32 bit). none more